# APE Install Missing File

Tags: mysql, fedora

After installing from the RPM and then trying the Binary versions of APE (AJAX Push Engine) I am getting this error (on both versions) when I try to run the APE server:

```
[Module] Failed to load ../modules/libmod_spidermonkey.so [Invalid library] (libmysqlclient_r.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

I am using Fedora Linux, with MySql and apache installed. How can I get this libmysqlclient file? I have found this RPM: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/12471829/dir/fedora_4/com/mysqlclient15-5.0.67-1.fc4.remi.i386.rpm.html

And it says it includes this file, so I downloaded it to the box, attempted to install and tells me that it's already installed.

Any advice would help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the ape.conf there's a module working directory which must be altered.